# In pandas, how do you find the time since a column by value changes, when grouped by another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame the looks like the following:

[image: Inital DataFrame]

I want to be able to calculate the time since a value changes in the "Project" and/or "Value" columns grouped by the "Name" column. How would I go about doing this? The output should be something like this (I don't care about the units):

[image: Final DataFrame]

Edit:

I think in my quest for brevity, I didn't completely explain the problem. I know this could be done with a for loop to check when a "Project" or "Value" changes and then compute the difference in datetime, but I was looking for a more vectorized approach. The real df I am working with is almost 1,000,000 rows and 1,000 columns. I made a bit of progress figuring out where a value changes (as .diff() doesn't work for strings) and the raw time changes with the following:

```py
df["Changes"] = df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: x['Project'].ne(x['Project'].shift().bfill())).values

df['Day Delta'] = df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: (x.Date -x.Date.shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[D]')).fillna(0).values
```

Resulting in:
[image]

I am still a bit lost figuring out how to translate this to the change in time since the last change.

Comment: [pandas.Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html#:~:text=Represents%20a%20duration%2C%20the%20difference,with%20it%20in%20most%20cases.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured out a way of doing this. I first modified the changes flag to give me a change on the first value:

```py
df["Project Change"] = df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: x['Project'].ne(x['Project'].shift().ffill())).values
```

Yielding:

[image: DataFrame with Changes]

I then did a date difference when the value was true, grouped by the name:

```py
df['Days Since Project Change'] = df['Date']-df['Date'].where(df["Project Change"]).groupby(df['Name']).ffill()
```

Resulting in:

[image: DataFrame Final]

Or, all together:

```py
df.drop(columns = ["Project Change"], inplace = True)

df['Days Since Value Change'] = df['Date']-df['Date'].where(df.groupby("Name").apply(lambda x: x['Value'].ne(x['Value'].shift().ffill())).values).groupby(df['Name']).ffill()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import datetime 

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
seq = int(dt.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

To transform your dates to integers. Then compare the values in the `Project` and `Value` column. If they are different, then calculate the difference between the dates (after you transformed the dates to integers) and you get your value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don’t think I was completely clear with my question - see my edit. I am looking for a vectorized way of comparing and then calculating the difference.